# How to Re-use HttpClient instance with different credentials per request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 application that includes a controller action that makes a HTTP request.
To do this, I am using HttpClient.

I have learnt from others (like this blog [post](http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)) and from my own experiences
as well that instantating numerous HttpClients simultaneously can have a negative effect on the performance of not just the application but the server as a whole.

So far my requirements of reusing a HttpClient instance could be solved by code like this

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(getUsername(), getHashedPassword())})
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
   // Long running loop that makes a different HTTP request
   // on each iteration but using the same HttpClient instance
}
```

Requiring similar re-use in a controller action, I elected to use
a static instance of HttpClient in the controller class. The problem is that
the credentials passed to the HttpClientHandler change with each request since
they partially depend on a timestamp value(the `getHashedPassword()` method produces a different password each time it is called).

Because of the way authentication is carried out on the remote server, I have to include the password in the XML content that forms the body of the request as well.

And this is where I run into the problem:

How can I re-use the same HttpClient instance across different calls to the controller action while making sure it is
using a handler with up to date credentials?

Is it even possible to do this?

Is it possible to update the handler after passing it to the HttpInstance?

Or would I need to modify the client object's DefaultRequestHeaders which according to some sources may introduce subtle bugs if the object is used concurrently by different threads?

Comment: Do you realize if you use an static HttpClient and multiple request are sent in parallell credentials will mix up? and also, all the methods non-static aren't thread safe. So that's not really a good idea at all...

Comment: @Gusman. I was not sure about that. That's part of the reason I was asking my question. I am looking for a way to achieve sharing the HttpClient in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: For what you want you need a pool of clients, something similar to how threadpool works, you have a maximum of clients set, you create your pool empty or with a minimum count of clients, when you want to use a client you ask the pool for one, if there's none left the pool creates a new one else it returns one from its internal list, then after you finish working with the client you return it to the pool and if the maximum of clients has been reached the pool destroys it, else stores it on its internal list ready for its next use. It's not a simple matter.

Comment: @Gusman re:"all the methods non-static aren't thread safe" that is not true.  "HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application".  Several instance members are thread-safe. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: This is an old question however will put this here to help anyone out there.  I don't think there's a way to update the credentials on a handler once passed to static instance of HttpClient. Although thread safe updating the shared state of DefaultRequestHeaders will also behave in an unexpected manner which is already pointed out.  Use `httpClient.SendAsync(request)` and construct the request object, adding to header property any credentials needed.

Comment: Consider using SocketsHttpClientHandler instead of HttpClientHandler. Not only it is bit better in performance, it exposes property named 'Credentials' which you can set before transmission. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1):

The HttpClientHandler object is a component that handles requests used by the HttpClient. You want to update the HttpClientHandler for every request that requires new credentials. There are several ways to do this.
You can set up-to-date credentials by creating a new HttpClientHandler instance before each request.

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
       handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(getUsername(), getHashedPassword());
       // HttpClient örneğini kullanarak istekleri gerçekleştirin
    }
```

By updating the DefaultRequestHeaders you can pass new credentials on every request.

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{getUsername()}:{getHashedPassword()}")));
   // HttpClient örneğini kullanarak istekleri gerçekleştirin
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `HTTPClient` directly, it is advised to create a client instance using `HTTPClientFactory`.
Once done, you can create `named clients` which can be reused based on your handlers.
Here is a [useful link](https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/05/22/named-http-clients-in-net-core-web-applications/) on the same.

If you want to further optimize your code, you can maintain a concurrent dictionary.

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, HTTPClient> _clientMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HTTPClient>();
```

This can then be leveraged like this:

```
using(var client = _clientMap.GetOrAdd($"{handlerName}", _clientFactory.CreateClient("handlerName"));
```

In the above snippet, `_clientFactory` refers to `IHttpClientFactory` instance.